# About isomorphism between fields formed by quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra

I often encounter trouble in proving isomorphism of things in terms of quotients, say is $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-3)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-2)$ or $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^3-3)$? Is there any way to attack such problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-3)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-2)$ because $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-3)$ has an element $u$ such that $u^5=3$ but $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-2)$ doesn't. (I'm guessing here, but for these examples it seems a safe guess.)

$\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-3)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^3-3)$ because $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^5-3)$ has dimension $5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ whereas $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/$(x^3-3)$ has dimension $3$.

These arguments above are typical for this task.

More generally, to prove that $A$ is not isomorphic to $B$ it suffices to find a property of $A$ that does not hold for $B$. The property needs to be invariant under isomorphisms. This happens in other areas as well. For instance, a connected space cannot be homeomorphic to a space that is not connected.